# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'break'

Tags: php

```php
<?php
    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
    public function write($session_id, $session_data)
    {
        // If the two IDs don't match, we have a session_regenerate_id() call
        // and we need to close the old handle and open a new one
        if ($session_id !== $this->_session_id && ($this->close() === $this->_failure OR $this->read($session_id) === $this->_failure))
        {
            return $this->_failure;
        }

        if ( ! is_resource($this->_file_handle))
        {
            return $this->_failure;
        }
        elseif ($this->_fingerprint === md5($session_data))
        {
            return ( ! $this->_file_new && ! touch($this->_file_path.$session_id))
                ? $this->_failure
                : $this->_success;
        }

        if ( ! $this->_file_new)
        {
            ftruncate($this->_file_handle, 0);
            rewind($this->_file_handle);
        }

        if (($length = strlen($session_data)) > 0)
        {
            for ($written = 0; $written < $length; $written += $result)
            {
                if (($result = fwrite($this->_file_handle, substr($session_data, $written))) === FALSE)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( ! is_int($result))
            {
                $this->_fingerprint = md5(substr($session_data, 0, $written));
                log_message('error', 'Session: Unable to write data.');
                return $this->_failure;
            }
        }

        $this->_fingerprint = md5($session_data);
        return $this->_success;
    }
```

> Message: syntax error, unexpected token "break"

What am I doing wrong here? Is there perhaps a problem somewhere else that could make this "unexpected break" error show up?

Comment: The code does _not_ raise any syntax error for me. I assume the error message refers to some other code section.

Comment: but in the message there is an error break written

Comment: Works for me. Try deleting all the whitespace between the `break` and the preceding `{` and re-typing it. UTF whitespace characters have been making the rounds recently thanks to a "helpful" recent firefox update changing copy/paste behaviour.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say with "but in the message there is an error break written". PHP error messages contain a file name and a line number.